# Sample geopandas data in networkx example

Tags: networkx, geopandas, geopackage

I am trying an example provided by `networkx` [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/geospatial/plot_points.html). This example uses a `geopandas` dataset in a filename `cholera_cases.pkdg`.

```
# read in example data from a geopackage file. Geopackages
# are a format for storing geographic data that is backed
# by sqlite. geopandas reads data relying on the fiona package,
# providing a high-level pandas-style interface to geographic data.
cases = geopandas.read_file("cholera_cases.gpkg")
```

The example, however, does not mention where and how to obtain this dataset. I combed GeoPandas website up and down and am unable to locate this file. I want to view the format of its content and run this example.

If anyone is aware of where to obtain this kind of `geopandas` file, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to their GitHub, you can find it in their repo. Here: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/tree/main/examples/geospatial

Might be worth cloning the repo to play with the examples.

As general advice, on webpages for projects like these, I like to always check for links to their GitHub/GitLab/other because you get to see the project behind the scenes, and a local clone can be kept up to date